# Should I go with PHP.NET and Resharper or PHPStorm

Tags: php, visual-studio

I am a fairly adept .NET and PHP programmer. These days my pattern of choice for complex web apps is an SOA approach where I use PHP as the front end, and WCF web services as the middle tier. My ajax calls are usually to JSON [webHttpBinding](http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx) WCF endpoints. On the .NET side of things I am absolutely in love with the Visual Studio plugin [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

So my question is as follows, I want to rethink my tool chain on the PHP side of things. On one side JetBrains, the makers of Resharper, have a PHP IDE called [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). On the other side, I can use VS.PHP and ReSharper. Does anyone use the later combination fo VS.PHP and Resharper? Can you recommend it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're also working with WCF Web Services, I'd recommend you stick with Visual Studio.

I've done quite a bit with that platform and it works well.  PHP Storm is probably very nice, but it's going to cost extra and be a new environment that you'll have to get used to.  If it's not broke, don't fix it :)

Comment: Well I'm not going to move away from Visual Studio. The question is two actually use IDEs or one.

Comment: @Justin I'd say one, then.  Although, I've started using Sublime Text for a lot of editing that doesn't require VS.